# Create form steps with Symfony 2?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I tried to create 2 form groups but I can see only the first group.

Is this the correct way to make a form group?

My Form Type Builder:

```
$builder->add(
    $builder->create('step1', 'form', array('virtual' => true))
        ->add('url')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('created_at'),

    $builder->create('step2', 'form', array('virtual' => true))
        ->add('user')
        ->add('tags', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'LanCrmBundle:LinkTag',
            'property' => 'title',
            'multiple' => true
        ))
);
```

My view :

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    <form method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Try to call the $builder->add sparately (twice). The first time on $builder->create() of the first step, the second time on the oter.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to create form steps with symfony 2, you can use the next bundle:

https://packagist.org/packages/craue/formflow-bundle

I used it and works fine.
You can see an example in:

http://www.craue.de/sf2playground/en/CraueFormFlow/